# To prove ring properties of analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $R$ be the ring of entire functions $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ that are analytic at every point of $\mathbb{C}$ with respect to point-wise addition and multiplication. Then show that
>
> (A) $R$ is an integral domain
>
> (B) the irreducible elements of $R$ are upto multiplication by units, polynomials of the form $z-\xi$.
>
> (C) $R$ is not a UFD

The first one is fairly easy to do as if $f$ and $g$ are  analytic functions such that $fg=0$ on a domain then $f\equiv 0$ or $g \equiv 0$ on some subset of the domain with non-empty interior hence $f\equiv 0$ or $g \equiv 0$ on the domain.

For part $B$ I believe I need a theorem that states in effect that entire functions can be written as product of polynomials $z-\xi$. I need some help with this one and C too. Thanks

Comment: I believe the Weierstrauss Factorization theorem should give you what you want, with regards to factoring entire functions.

Comment: And for part C, you want to consider the fact that some analytic functions have infinitely man zeroes, so they cannot be written as a finite product.

Comment: Yup thanks. I read the Wikipedia article on Weierstrauss Factorization theorem it helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

$f$ is a unit iff it has no zeros.  If it has a zero at $z=a$, then $g(z) = f(z)/(z-a)$ has a removable singularity at $a$; after removing that singularity, it is entire.  Show that $f$ is irreducible iff $g$ is a unit.