# Does the ring of analytic functions have zero divisors?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, ring-theory, analytic-functions

**Question** I have to show that the ring of complex analytic functions on **open** unit disk has no zero divisors.

**My attempt** let suppose $fg≡0$ such that $f≢0$ and $g≢0$ on open unit disk $U$ then $f$ and $g$ have finitely many zeros on $U$ and so that $fg$ have finitely many zeros on $U$ and hence $fg≢0$. Hence we must have either $f≡0$ or $g≡0$. Hence given ring has no zero divisors.

I am not that good in complex analysis. However i am familiar with abstract algebra.

So please give details. Is my attempt correct? I didnt know, why $f$ and $g$ have finitely many zeros on $U$?  please elaborate this point too.

Please help...

Comment: Yes, the ring of analytic functions on $U\subset \Bbb{C}$ connected open is an integral domain and the ring of meromorphic functions is a field. This is more or less immediate from the Taylor/Laurent expansion at $z_0$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496760/if-fzgz-0-for-every-z-then-fz-0-or-gz-0-for-every-z

Comment: @ThomasShelby sir thank you so much for link.

Comment: Another [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1829437/to-prove-ring-properties-of-analytic-functions).

Comment: The answers show you that there can be infinitely many zeroes, however a nonzero holomorphic function cannot have uncountably many zeroes on its domain of holomorphicity (assuming it is a connected domain). To see why connected is important: consider two separate discs and pick a function that is $0$ on one piece and $1$ on the other. This theorem fails in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to find analytic functions defined on the open unit disc having **infinitely** many zeros. For example, consider the [Blaschke product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaschke_product). Another example, given in Conway's *Functions of One Complex Variable*, is $$f(z)=\cos\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right),\;|z|\lt 1.$$ But if $f$ is a nonzero analytic function on the **closed** unit disc, it can only have finitely many zeros. To see this, note that every infinite subset of a compact set has a limit point.

As I mentioned in the comment section, the standard approach to this problem is to use the identity theorem and a solution can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496760/if-fzgz-0-for-every-z-then-fz-0-or-gz-0-for-every-z?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Sir, as in my question $U$ is open disk, how solution in link works?

Comment: $U$ is a connected open set. So just replace the $\Omega $ with $U$. I hope you're familiar with the identity theorem and its various forms.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea that $f$ and $g$ have a finite numbers of $0$ is not true. However, there's still a proof based on the number of zeros, a more "algebraic"-flavored proof:

If $fg\equiv 0$; $\{f=0\}\cup \{g=0\}=\mathbb{D}$. However, if the two functions are not identically zero they can have at maximum a countable number of zeros, which gives a contradiction.
To prove that the set of zeros is countable, note that
$\mathbb{D}=\cup_{\mathbb{N}} \{|z|\le 1-\frac1n\}$, so if one of the two functions (lets say $f$) has more than a countable number of zeros, at least a countable number of them is contained in one of those sets $\{|z|\le 1-\frac1n\}$. Since they are compact, this implies that the set of zeros has a cluster point, which by the identity theorem implies that $f\equiv 0$, a contradiction.

Another interesting thing about the set of holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{D}$ is that, while it is an integral domain, it is not a UFD: the irreducible elements are the [Blaschke factors](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BlaschkeFactor.html), but not every element can be written as a *finite* product of them, as $$\sin\left(\frac{1}{z-1}\right)$$ shows.
This also implies that this set is not a Noetherian ring.

Comment: Nice proof! (+1)

Comment: Sir, what is $D$ here?  Domain? (Open connected set)

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi $\mathbb D$ is the open unit disc($U$).